How to send file from server to client over ssh in golang?
I am using wish and bubbletea, to create an app and send it over ssh. the app just has the things I have worked on, a github link, and the bit I am stuck on, a download. then it will go to https://raw.githubusercontent.com///main/ or it will go to the realeases. It will get the data then send it over ssh to the client, and I can see the content of the file is displayed on the client as text. But I don't know how to create a file on the user's side and put the content of the file into it. I can't find anything on the internet about sending from the server to the client only the client to the server. I just don't know how to execute code on the client's side (creating the file and putting data into it). Any solutions? Thanks in advance.
func (m *model) downloadFile(url string) {
    // Get the file from the URL
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        m.status = fmt.Sprintf("Failed to download: %v\n", err)
        m.Session.Write([]byte(m.status))
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // Check if the request succeeded
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        m.status = fmt.Sprintf("HTTP Error: %v\n", resp.Status)
        m.Session.Write([]byte(m.status))
        return
    }

    // Notify user of file transfer
    m.Session.Write([]byte("Starting file transfer..."))

    // Copy file data to the SSH session
    _, err = io.Copy(m.Session, resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        m.status = fmt.Sprintf("Error sending file: %v\n", err)
        m.Session.Write([]byte(m.status))
        return
    }

    // Notify the user that the transfer is complete
    m.Session.Write([]byte("\nFile transfer complete!\n"))
    m.status = "Download completed!\n"
}



The server does not send data unrequested. Perhaps look into using sftp

You can't force to create a file at the client side. You should create a download possibility where the client can download his "content".
